# What is the set of all isometric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, isometry, projection-matrices

An isometry from metric space $X=\mathbb{R}^{d}$ to metric space $Y=\mathbb{R}^{k}$ with usual norm for both spaces is the following:

$$
\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}
$$
where $\Phi(x)=Px$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$ such that $\|x\|_2^2=\|Px\|_2^2$. The set of all $P$'s can be written as

$$
\mathcal{P}=\{P \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d} \mid \|x\|_2^2=\|Px\|_2^2 \,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}\}
$$

My questions:

Is $\mathcal{P}$ the set of all $P \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$ where each column is a Euclidean basis $e_i=[0,0,\cdots,0,\overbrace{1}^{i},0,\cdots,0]^{T}$?

If so, why this is true and we have only zero and 1 in the isometry?

Comment: No.  $\mathcal P$ is the set of all $P$ satisfying $P^TP = I_d$, where $I_d$ is the $d \times d$ identity matrix.

Comment: But $P$ is $d \times k$, shouldn't be $P^TP=I_k$?

Comment: If $\Phi$ goes from $X$ to $Y$, then $P$ should be $k\times d$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yes. you are right. I edited it. $P$ can be any matrix with $d$ colums including orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: that's exactly right

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: From the above, can we conclude that we need a set of orthonormal basis in $Y$ to build an isometry? and generalize this to any pair of Hilbert spaces $X,Y$ and say to build an isometry that maps $X$ to $Y$ we need orthonormal basis in Hilbert space $Y$?

Comment: For arbitrary maps between Hilbert spaces, we don't normally talk about the columns of an associated matrix.  However, it is true that any isometry between Hilbert spaces will map an orthonormal basis of $X$ (a canonical orthonormal basis, if you prefer) to an orthonormal subset of $Y$.